My custom templatetag is not working. The output is empty
Here's the folder structure:
homepage (this is the Django app)
|
|templatetags
|  __init__.py
|  shamsi_tags.py

The content of shamsi_tags.py:
from datetime import datetime

from django import template

from jdatetime import datetime as jdatetime

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def shamsi_date():
    """
    This template tag returns the current date in Shamsi format.
    """
    now = datetime.now()
    shamsi_date = jdatetime.fromgregorian(now.year, now.month, now.day)
    return shamsi_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

The index.html:
{% load shamsi_tags %}
...
<div>{{ shamsi_date }}</div>
...

And nothing displays. I check the page source and it shows <div></div>.
The rest of the page is displaying correctly so I guess there's nothing wrong with the URL or view.
Obviously jdatetime is installed.
It is Django 5.0.6 on Windows.
I'm sure this is something easy but I can't figure it out.

I think you are misunderstanding how simple tags work in Django.  Tags work like this:
{{ some_value | lower_tag }}

You define a tag like:
@register.simple_tag
def lower(some_value):
   return some_value.lower()

In your scenario, you are simply trying to use the tag without a value.  If you want to give the shamsi_date to the HTML template, you can simply make it a regular function, and pass it to the template when you send it to the user.
def shamsi_date():
    now = datetime.now()
    shamsi_date = jdatetime.fromgregorian(now.year, now.month, now.day)
    return shamsi_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

# Assuming you have an index function
def index(request):
    # rest of function
    shamsi = shamsi_date()
    render(request, "index.html", {"shamsi_date" : shamsi })

After this, you should be able to get the shamsi_date by doing {{ shamsi_date }}

My reference is Django's documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags. What you are referring to is template filter.
